# Cocoapods install getting error

Tags: ios7, cocoapods

Here is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, ‘7.0’

pod 'ECSlidingViewController', '~> 2.0.0'
```

When I type pod install into the terminal, this is the error I get:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: /Users/Kyle/Desktop/Testing/Podfile:1: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
platform :ios, ‘7.0’
                    ^
/Users/Kyle/Desktop/Testing/Podfile:1: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting '('
platform :ios, ‘7.0’
                     ^. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.
```

Everything in the Podfile seems correct. I have tried with " instead of ' with no effect. I have also removed the decimal (the dot) and moved it around. Am I missing something?

After trolling through the web, one user suggested that something might be wrong with my Ruby installation, but how can I check that? I have also verified that I installed all Ruby updates with this:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Had this same issue. It's difficult to notice, but if you're on a Mac and used TextEdit to edit the Podfile, the quote character was probably changed. Turn off 'Smart Quotes' in Preferences.

Comment: I turn off 'Smart Quotes' in Preferences,but what I type is still curly quotes.Why?

Comment: @nimingzhe2008 Go to Edit -> Substitutions -> Smart Quotes make sure it's unticked to update an already in use document that started off with Smart Quotes.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same issue the following worked for me. In replace curly quotes in Podfile's first line i.e

```
platform :ios, ‘7.0’ (Not working)
platform :ios, '7.0' (Working)
```

You are using curly quotes character, which is **‘=0x2018** & **’=0x2019**. You should use straight quote which is **'=0x27**

TextEdit automatically converts *normal quotes* to *smart quotes*. You can disable smart quotes option from :
System Preferences -> Keyboard -> uncheck 'Use smart quotes and dashes'

[image: System preferences -> Keyboard]